# Bug unserialize data PHP doesnt work

Tags: php, serialization

I have this data:

```
{"2":{"label":"","value":"","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"3":{"label":"location","value":"","type":"hidden","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"1000","tooltip":"","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"4":{"label":"Email","value":"","type":"email","validation":"email","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field0","custom":"","custom2":"","custom3":"zz","custom4":"","custom5":""},"5":{"label":"divider","value":"Group","type":"divider","validation":"divider","required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"6":{"label":"Nom","value":"nom","type":"text","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"300","tooltip":"field2","custom":"","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"7":{"label":"Ville","value":"ville","type":"text","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"300","tooltip":"field3","custom":"","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"8":{"label":"Code postal","value":"57000","type":"text","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"300","tooltip":"field4","custom":"","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"9":{"label":"Description","value":"des","type":"para","validation":"","required":"0","min":"0","max":"300","tooltip":"field5","custom":"","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"10":{"label":"Note","value":"4","type":"stars","validation":"","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field6","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"11":{"label":"Note-Reason","value":"","type":"stars","validation":"","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field6","custom":"reason","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"12":{"label":"divider","value":"Group","type":"divider","validation":"divider","required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"13":{"label":"Image","value":"1","type":"upload","validation":"file","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field8","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"14":{"label":"files","value":"http:\/\/www.test.com\/images.jpg","type":"file0","validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"15":{"label":"name","value":"","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"16":{"label":"title","value":"Form Title","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"17":{"label":"emails","value":",","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"18":{"label":"multi","value":"true","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null,"custom5":null},"0":{"custom3":"zz","value":"","label":""},"1":{"custom3":"zz","value":"","label":""}}
```

Then i do this in PHP to get an image :

```
$content = unserialize($data);
echo $content[14]['value'];
```

And nothing happen, what is the error ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's JSON encoded not serialized.

Comment: Add quotes. $content['14'] ...

Comment: And this is why you don't simply take random functions and throw them at random data. This is simply the wrong input for this function, or the wrong function for this input if you like that better.

Comment: Sorry i'am novice in programmation its works with json decode.

Answer (score -1):

This is not PHP serialized data, use `json_decode()`:

```
print_r(json_decode($data, true));
```

Comment: Technically it's serialized, but into JSON, and not PHP's format (idk whether it has a name). Regardless, `unserialize()` will not work on it :).

Comment: Mark as answered please.  Don't know why the downvote.